# grep not working in while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, scripting, grep

I am trying to make a monitoring script and to contact specified person in case of special event, the first `egrep` in below code worked fine but the second one didn't work at all, please help:

```
while true; do
  tail -f /Testing/script/errors | egrep -o --line-buffer "Timeout" >> wch.txt;
  cat /Testing/script/contacts.txt|egrep --line-buffer "FB" | cut -f2 -d ":" >> mail.txt;
  sleep 5
done
```

contact.txt:

FB:Kh.ismail014@gmail.com
Google:Amr.elrefaie@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option as `--line-buffer`, perhaps you meant `--line-buffered`, it's a GNU-ism.

The second `grep` could be simplified as:

```
grep --line-buffered 'FB' /Testing/script/contacts.txt | cut -f2 -d ":" >> mail.txt
```

You are not using any Extended Regex pattern, so there is no point using `egrep` (`grep -E`). Also you don't need `cat`, and piping, `grep` takes filename as argument.

Similarly the first `grep` can be written as:

```
tail -f /Testing/script/errors | grep -o --line-buffered "Timeout" >> wch.txt
```

So your `while` construct:

```
while :;  do
    tail -f /Testing/script/errors | egrep -o --line-buffer "Timeout" >> wch.txt
    grep --line-buffered 'FB' /Testing/script/contacts.txt | cut -f2 -d ":" >> mail.txt
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: I did as you told me as shown below and it didn't work:

Comment: while true
do

tail -f /Testing/script/errors | egrep -o --line-buffer "Timeout" >> wch.txt;

grep --line-buffered 'FB' /Testing/script/contacts.txt | cut -f2 -d ":" >> mail.txt

sleep 5

done

Comment: the first grep worked fine but the second one still not working maybe it is not the grep or what ?

Comment: @khaledIsmail Whats the output of `cat /Testing/script/contacts.txt`?

Comment: FB:Kh.ismail014@gmail.com
Google:Amr.elrefaie@gmail.com

Comment: @khaledIsmail Please add this to your question.

Comment: Done, is there any solution for this ?

Comment: @khaledIsmail This should work perfectly. Whats the output of `grep --line-buffered 'FB' /Testing/script/contacts.txt | cut -f2 -d ":"`?

Answer (score 0):

The `-f` flag in the 2nd line is blocking the loop. The output is appending new lines in `/Testing/script/errors` as the file grows.